# Three.js, I updated from r152 to r153, why are the particles brighter?

Tags: three.js

**Is there any way to restore the previous effect without downgrading it?**

After updating to version r153, the particle effect is not the same and I can't find a solution to this problem from the [official migration guide](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide#152--153).

You can go to [Codepen-demo](https://codepen.io/Lightning-Development-Team/pen/XWQMyqp)
Or look My code:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 24px;
    overscroll-behavior: none;
}
```

```html
<script type="importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "three": "https://unpkg.com/three/build/three.module.js",
        "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.152.0/examples/jsm/"
      }
    }
</script>

<script type="module">
    import * as THREE from 'three';
    import {EffectComposer} from "three/addons/postprocessing/EffectComposer";
    import {RenderPass} from "three/addons/postprocessing/RenderPass";
    import {GlitchPass} from "three/addons/postprocessing/GlitchPass";
    import {ShaderPass} from "three/addons/postprocessing/ShaderPass";
    import {UnrealBloomPass} from "three/addons/postprocessing/UnrealBloomPass";
    import {FocusShader} from "three/addons/shaders/FocusShader";

    const width = window.innerWidth, height = window.innerHeight

    THREE.ColorManagement.enabled = false

    let bufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    let group = new THREE.Group();
    let surroundParticleGroup = new THREE.Group();
    let composer, glitchPass
    let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 10, 10000);
    camera.position.z = 750;

    let scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(0x02050c, 0.0025);
    scene.background = scene.fog.color
    scene.add(group);
    scene.add(surroundParticleGroup);

    let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    renderer.setClearColor(scene.fog.color);
    renderer.autoClear = false
    renderer.render(scene, camera)

    let total = 8000,
            minZVal = window.innerWidth * 0.5,
            minYVal = window.innerHeight * 1.2;

    const points = []
    const colors = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        const vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
        vertex.x = rangeRandom(minZVal, -minZVal);
        vertex.y = rangeRandom(minYVal, -minYVal);
        vertex.z = rangeRandom(minZVal, -minZVal);
        points.push(vertex)
        colors.push(255, 255, 255)
    }

    bufferGeometry.setFromPoints(points);
    bufferGeometry.setAttribute("color", new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(colors, 3));

    const material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
        size: 8,
        color: 0x01050f,
        alphaTest: 0.7,
        map: null,
        vertexColors: true
    });

    group.add(new THREE.Points(bufferGeometry, material));
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    late()
    animate()

    function rangeRandom(max, min) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    }

    function animate() {
        renderer.render(scene, camera)
        composer.render();
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    function late() {
        const renderScene = new RenderPass(scene, camera)
        const bloomPass = new UnrealBloomPass(new THREE.Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight), 1.5, 0, 0.18)
        const focusShader = new ShaderPass(FocusShader)

        focusShader.uniforms["screenWidth"].value = window.innerWidth;
        focusShader.uniforms["screenHeight"].value = window.innerHeight;
        focusShader.uniforms["sampleDistance"].value = 0.01;
        bloomPass.renderToScreen = true
        composer = new EffectComposer(renderer)
        composer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)

        let DarkMaskShader = {
            uniforms: {
                "tDiffuse": {
                    value: null
                },
                "maskColor": {
                    value: new THREE.Color(0x02050c)
                },
                "maskAlpha": {
                    value: 1.0
                },
                "markRadius": {
                    value: 0.1
                },
                "smoothSize": {
                    value: 0.5
                }
            },
            vertexShader: [
                "varying vec2 vUv;",
                "void main() {",
                "   vUv = uv;",
                "   gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );",
                "}"
            ].join("\n"),
            fragmentShader: [
                "uniform float maskAlpha;",
                "uniform vec3 maskColor;",
                "uniform float markRadius;",
                "uniform float smoothSize;",
                "uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;",
                "varying vec2 vUv;",
                "float sdfCircle(vec2 coord, vec2 center, float radius)",
                "{",
                "   vec2 offset = coord - center;",
                "   return sqrt((offset.x * offset.x) + (offset.y * offset.y)) - radius;",
                "}",
                "void main() {",
                "   vec4 texel = texture2D( tDiffuse, vUv );",
                "   float sdfValue = sdfCircle(vUv, vec2(0.5, 0.5), markRadius);",
                "   if (sdfValue < 0.0){",
                "       gl_FragColor = texel;",
                "   }else{",
                "       float a = smoothstep(0.0, smoothSize, sdfValue);",
                "       gl_FragColor = mix(texel, vec4(maskColor, maskAlpha), a);",
                "   }",
                "}"
            ].join("\n")
        }

        let effectDarkMask = new ShaderPass(DarkMaskShader);

        composer.addPass(renderScene)
        composer.addPass(bloomPass)
        glitchPass = new GlitchPass()
        composer.addPass(glitchPass)
        composer.addPass(effectDarkMask)
        glitchPass.curF = 0
        glitchPass.randX = 0
    }
</script>
```

I tried the "color space" related changes myself and concluded that the problem occurs in "function late()"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define that your texture holds sRGB colors. Do this like so:

```js
mapDot.colorSpace = THREE.SRGBColorSpace;
```

> I tried usd this code, but it made the particles darker than before.

When you define color values with CSS and hex colors, `three.js` automatically recognizes them as sRGB colors and converts them for you to the `linear-srgb` working color space. So there is no need to call `convertSRGBToLinear()` in this case.

Edit: When doing post post processing, you should add an instance of `OutputPass` at the end of your pass chain. This pass takes care of tone mapping (if configured) and sRGB color space conversion. Import it like so:

```js
import { OutputPass } from 'three/addons/postprocessing/OutputPass.js';
```

And add it to the composer like so:

```js
const outputPass = new OutputPass();
composer.addPass(outputPass);
```

Note that there were some important fixes in the post-processing stack with `r153` which ensure HDR, tone mapping and color space conversion work as expected now. The look in the following fiddle is now "correct" from a rendering point of view: https://jsfiddle.net/cjw9h16u/2/

You might want to tweak the bloom settings or the tone mapping exposure to customize the brightness in your scene.

Comment: Sorry about that, I did some troubleshooting and realized that the problem wasn't here, it was in another place, I re-edited the question and added "codepen"

Comment: I have updated my answer to explain a bit the post processing related changes.